# Can Samsung Pass SDK be used with other manufactures for implement fingerprint scanner in App?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, fingerprint, samsung-mobile-sdk

For implementing fingerprint scanner in S6, I am going to use Samsung PASS SDK. I want to know whether the SDK will work with other manufactures fingerprint scanner enabled android devices.

Thanks…

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the Pass SDK is for Samsung devices with built in fingerprint sensor.

> Pass API is released as part of the Samsung Mobile SDK 1.5 beta1
>   during the launch of Samsung Galaxy S5 mobile phone.

via [Pocket-lint](http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/127567-samsung-will-let-developers-use-galaxy-s5-s-fingerprint-scanner-in-apps).

**EDIT:**

As the official [Samsung dev. portal FAQ](http://developer.samsung.com/resources/pass#none) (page 2) points out:

> **Q: What devices can use the Pass SDK?**
>
> **A:** Any Samsung Mobile device that supports the fingerprint sensor and
>   the Fingerprint Service with Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean API 17) and
>   above.

Answer (score 1):

So far I know about Samsung Pass SDK, as it allows you to use the Samsung Fingerprint Service features so you must use any Samsung Mobile device that supports the fingerprint sensor and the Fingerprint Service with Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean API 17) and above.